# How to update a pip package without resetting its CSV files to its original state

Tags: pypi

I'm trying to publish my own pip package that contains a few CSV files that are going to be filled with continuous user use. I tried to do test update to my PyPI package and noticed that the CSV files get reset to their original state. How do I release new versions of my pip package without affecting/resetting some file types such as the CSV files?

Currently, my `MANIFEST.in` file contains the following line

```
graft package
```

And within the package directory, there is a bunch of Python and CSV files.

Comment: This is a pretty uncommon behavior for a Python package. What is the use case here? Why do you need to persist this data?

Comment: I'm making a Discord bot that reports data received from a game API, but only to those who register via a command in the Discord chat. To keep track of who registered and who did not, I need to store that information in CSV files. So any pip update can cause those CSV files to reset and thus losing track of the server users.

Comment: Sounds like you should probably configure it to use a database or some other external data store. Python packages don't usually contain stateful data like this.